# How to order a Dictionary or Tuple by value in a spark data frame column?

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to sort a dictionary descending by the value in a spark data frame. I have tried many different ways, including ways not shown below. I have found many responses on ordering a python dictionary, but they are not working in my case.

I have tried Ordered Dict and Sorted.

I am not picky about the output being a dictionary, **it can also be a tuple**.

Sample Data:

```
a = ["This is dummy data this dummy data is being used for word counts","See if this will work see if working not working", "Is this working is this working maybe it is maybe it isnt", "hopefully this works"]
b = [1,2,1,2]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(b, a), schema=['id', 'text'])
```

Code I wrote to prepare the data:

```
def MostCommonWords(data):

  #agg text by id
  GroupedText = data.groupby("id").agg(F.concat_ws(", ", F.collect_list(data.text)).alias('aggText'))

  #tokenizing text to count in the next step
  tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='aggText', outputCol='textTokenized')
  GroupedText = tokenizer.transform(GroupedText)

  #creating udf from counter function and applying udf to tokenized text
  CounterUDF = F.udf(lambda x: dict(Counter(x)), MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
  GroupedText = GroupedText.withColumn('WordFrequency', CounterUDF(F.col("textTokenized")))

  #Top 10 most frequent words for each id
  Nlargest_UDF = F.udf(lambda x: dict(heapq.nlargest(10, x.items(), key=itemgetter(1))), MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
  MostCommon = GroupedText.withColumn('MostCommon', Nlargest_UDF(F.col("WordFrequency")))

  MostCommon = MostCommon.select('id','MostCommon')
  return MostCommon

MostCommon = MostCommonWords(df)
```

Different ways I have tried to sort the dictionaries in each row:

```
naming = collections.namedtuple('Word', 'Count')
#SorterUDF = F.udf(lambda x: sorted([naming(v,k) for (k,v) in x.items(), key=itemgetter(1)], MapType(StringType(), IntegerType(), reverse=True)))
#SorterUDF = F.udf(lambda x: {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse = True)})
#SorterUDF = F.udf(lambda x: dict(sorted(x.items(), key=itemgetter(1))), MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
SorterUDF = F.udf(lambda x: OrderedDict(sorted(x.items(), key=itemgetter(1))), MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
Sortedd = MostCommon.withColumn('SortedMostCommon', SorterUDF(F.col("MostCommon")))
```

I am not getting errors, it is simply just not sorting. 
Expected Result: Dictionary or tuple in each row sorted by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark doesn't have ordered `MapType`. The current `MapType` is converted to and from `dict` type internally. So I guess we have to use an `ArrayType` of `StructType` instead.

```
def sort_dict_f(x):
    sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return sorted_x

schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("word", StringType(), False), StructField("count", IntegerType(), False)
]))

SorterUDF = F.udf(sort_dict_f, schema)
df = MostCommon.withColumn('SortedMostCommon', SorterUDF("MostCommon"))
df.show()
print(df.take(1)[0]['SortedMostCommon'])
```

The output:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|          MostCommon|    SortedMostCommon|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|[dummy -> 2, isnt...|[[isnt,, 1], [bei...|
|  2|[not -> 1, see ->...|[[will, 1], [work...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+

[Row(word='isnt,', count=1), Row(word='being', count=1), Row(word='used', count=1), Row(word='working', count=2), Row(word='maybe', count=2), Row(word='it', count=2), Row(word='dummy', count=2), Row(word='data', count=2), Row(word='this', count=4), Row(word='is', count=5)]
```

You can see that the words are properly sorted by their counts now.

Comment: You are welcome, btw, you may want to take a look at `StringIndexer, CountVectorizer` from pyspark.ml.feature. You may avoid customized structure like above. Also, please accept the answer if you think it's solved your issue :)

Comment: can you please have a look in my doubt (similar to this) whenever you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553746/tricky-pyspark-value-sorting